# $.ajax issue - Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: php, jquery

Hey guys I have the following:

```
function sendUserfNotes()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name,
        },
        success: function() {

             }
    });
    }
```

I am trying to send a value - notes_name over to a .php file so I can use GET[''] but I get a weird error - `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

the notes_name is defined at the bottom of the script based on if a link is clicked

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".NotesAccessor").click(function () {
        notes_name = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_table");
      run();
    });
    });
```

The run() triggers a dialog box in Jquery ui and runs this function where I am getting the error.

I don't know why I am getting this?

David

UPDATE:

I figured that it is with defining the JavaScript value to 'nameNotes':  the notes_name is defined after this code but that shouldn't matter.  So how would I assign the JavaScript variable to this?

Comment: Probably because `notes_name` is a jQuery object and whatever jQuery does to serialise the data, it does not like it. What did you expect to receive as value on the server side?

Comment: a name from a php variable so the javascript var will be like david or something

Comment: If you're trying to `$_GET` the values, you should use `type: "GET"` to send it as GET and not POST

Comment: As I said, `.find(".user_table")` returns a jQuery object, not a string. Fix that and it will probably work.

Comment: @subhaze I am having trouble getting var after sending it in ajax i used echo $_GET['nameNotes']; in that file that JQuery ui - dialog opens and changed the type to get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're assigning a jQuery object to `notes_name`, instead of a string (or some other basic type, like an int). This causes the `$.ajax` call to fail. Depending on what the `.user_table` element contains, use either `.value()` or `.text()` (or something of the sort) to extract the desired string instead of using a jQuery object.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks I used the .text()...you are the winner :)