# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

`Im having an Uncaught TypeError: illegal Invocation` problem on `Jquery 1.7.2` that is my code below where I call `onClick event` and i append the resultant data into the `div` having `list_data` as an `id`.

```
function click() {
    var url = 'show_data.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {'region_name': 'somewhere'},
        success: function (results) {
            $('#list_data').html(results);
        }
    });
}
```

I read allot other `Invocation Problem` here at stackoverflow but did not see the solution of my problem. Need some help here.

**solution**

instead of using the `data:{values}`, I removed that and add the variables directly in my url and go with the suggestion of Anoop.

my final code was:

```
var url = 'show_data.php?region_name=somewhere';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (results) {
                $('#list_data').html(results);
            }
        });
```

and you can use your own variables if you want. just go with the proper `url syntax`

Comment: try with url?region_name=somewhere

Comment: Try to use the `POST` method and use the `dataType:'json'`

Comment: @AnoopJoshi i tried with the full URL?region_name=somewhere but still the same error

Comment: @dhana i added `dataType` and changed `GET` to `POST`. still same error :c

Comment: @rockStar What is 'somewhere' ?

Comment: the value of `region_name` because at the `show_data.php` im getting it.

Comment: @dhana: That doesn't make sense. The OP is not even sending JSON.

Comment: See if this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794037/ajax-issue-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation.

Comment: Can you expose the URL where show_data.php exists so that we can take a detailed look?

Comment: If you are getting the value of region_name in show_data.php, then the error is occurring after the server has sent the data. Try putting `dataType: html` in the AJAX options. Also ensure show_data.php always returns HTML.

Comment: thank you guys, i did find a solution.

Comment: Could you share the solution you found? It might be helpful for others.

Comment: added it, and hope it'll be useful.